# Nuget package installed from local feed showing different meta data code in different projects

Tags: c#, .net, nuget, nuget-package

I had to create changes to a nuget package code. I have made the changes, and created a local nuget feed with my nuget package. When I install this nuget package in a new project, and I click to see the nuget package code (metadata), I see the correct code. But when I install this same nuget package in the project which is suppose to use this nuget package, I don't see some of the changes that I have made. I can see some new changes, I can't see others. How can a nuget package from the same feed behave differently in 2 different projects?

Comment: How are you creating this new nuget package? What are the steps you are following?

Comment: These are the commands I am using:
```dotnet pack example.csproj 

cd bin/debug
 
nuget add example.nupkg -source "local-nuget" -expand```